# Plotting tetrahedron with data points in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I'm in a little bit of pain at the moment.

I'm looking for a way to plot compositional data.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositional_data). I have four categories so data must be representable in a 3d simplex ( since one category is always 1 minus the sum of others).

So I have to plot a **tetrahedron** (edges will be my four categories) that contains my data points.

I've found this github https://gist.github.com/rmaia/5439815 but the use of `pavo` package(tcs, vismodel...) is pretty obscure to me.

I've also found something else in composition package, with function plot3D. But in this case an RGL device is open(?!) and I don't really need a rotating plot but just a static plot, since I want to save as an image and insert into my thesis.

Update: data looks like this. Consider only columns violent_crime (total), rape, murder, robbery, aggravated_assault

```
[  cities    violent_crime  murder rape rape(legally revised) robbery
1   Autauga            68      2    8                    NA       6
2   Baldwin            98      0    4                    NA      18
3   Barbour            17      2    2                    NA       2
4      Bibb             4      0    1                    NA       0
5    Blount            90      0    6                    NA       1
6   Bullock            15      0    0                    NA       3
7    Butler            44      1    7                    NA       4
8   Calhoun            15      0    3                    NA       1
9  Chambers             4      0    0                    NA       2
10 Cherokee            49      2    8                    NA       2
   aggravated_assault
1                  52
2                  76
3                  11
4                   3
5                  83
6                  12
7                  32
8                  11
9                   2
10                 37
```

Update: my final plot with composition package

[image]

Comment: Interesting question. Would you be able to share at least a portion of your data and the code you've tried?

Comment: Finally i manage to do a representation with compositions package and save with a screenshot. code:   library(compositions)

punti<-as.data.frame(na.omit(crime_county[,c(5,6,8,9)]))
plot3D.acomp(acomp(punti),1:4,col="green",size=4,vlabs.col = "black",scale=T)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do this without a dedicated package by using `geometry` and `plot3D`. Using the data you provided:

```r
# Load test data
df <- read.csv("test.csv")[, c("murder", "robbery", "rape", "aggravated_assault")]

# Convert absolute data to relative
df <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) x / sum(x)))

# Compute tetrahedron coordinates according to https://mathoverflow.net/a/184585
simplex <- function(n) {
  qr.Q(qr(matrix(1, nrow=n)) ,complete = TRUE)[,-1]
}
tetra <- simplex(4)

# Convert barycentric coordinates (4D) to cartesian coordinates (3D)
library(geometry)
df3D <- bary2cart(tetra, df)

# Plot data
library(plot3D)
scatter3D(df3D[,1], df3D[,2], df3D[,3],
          xlim = range(tetra[,1]), ylim = range(tetra[,2]), zlim = range(tetra[,3]),
          col = "blue", pch = 16, box = FALSE, theta = 120)
lines3D(tetra[c(1,2,3,4,1,3,1,2,4),1],
        tetra[c(1,2,3,4,1,3,1,2,4),2],
        tetra[c(1,2,3,4,1,3,1,2,4),3],
        col = "grey", add = TRUE)
text3D(tetra[,1], tetra[,2], tetra[,3],
       colnames(df), add = TRUE)
```

[image]

You can tweak the orientation with the `phi` and `theta` arguments in `scatter3D`.

Comment: Excellent solution! Minor note: `bary2cart` takes matrices as arguments. If your data come in a data frame `df`, you have to convert that first with `as.matrix(df)`