# Plotting 4 & 3 dimensional data - matlab

Tags: math, 4d, xna-math-library

I have data set to plot with the following dimensions.

1. Density
2. Accessibility
3. Land use mix
4. Vibrancy

Help me with the steps of the task.

Expected output will be [image]

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467254/plotting-tetrahedron-with-data-points-in-r which talks about a similar problem which apparently got solved in R

Answer (score 0):

It looks like somebody implemented a `QUATPLOT(A,B,C,D,marker,string)` function in Matlab:

> Percentage values (A,B,C,D) are transformed into xyz coordinates, allowing plotting % of data in the tetrahedron.

Source code and documentation can be found at https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/68595-3d-plotting-in-a-four-variable-system-quatplot